# C# Read <system.net><mailSettings> in web.config from external dll

Tags: c#, dll, smtp, web-config

My web app calls an external dll.  Within the dll I want to access the specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation value within the system.net/mailSettings/smtp section.  How can I grab it from within the dll code?

Something like

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp/specifiedPickupDirectory/pickupDirectoryLocation")
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

```
public string GetPickupDirectory()
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;

    return (config != null) ? config.SpecifiedPickupDirectory : null;
}
```

Comment: Great - thanks very much. I tweaked to deliver PickupDirectoryLocation.

public string GetPickupDir()
        {
            var config =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection;

            return (config != null) ? config.SpecifiedPickupDirectory.PickupDirectoryLocation : null;
        }

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could simply use the [PickupDirectoryLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation.aspx) property.

```
// if .NET 4.0 don't forget that SmtpClient is IDisposable
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
string pickupLocation = client.PickupDirectoryLocation;
```

This way you are not using magic strings in your code and it makes one less thing to worry about if in future versions of the framework this attribute changes name or location in the configuration file.

Comment: Good point, the SmtpClient automatically uses the configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
```

then:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
```

then you'll have access to

```
//settings.Smtp.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
```

Of course this should also be found in the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation property